# Could one make an electrostatic "permanent magnet"?

Tags: electrostatics, insulators

Could one make a negatively-charged insulator with the extra electrons trapped all the way through its volume by building it up layer by layer with electrons "sprayed" onto each layer as it was constructed?

I probably shouldn't have used the term magnet as I am thinking of an object with an overall charge and not a dipole.

Comment: Is [an electret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret) what you're looking for?

Comment: I guess electrets are dipoles whereas I was thinking of a unipole.

Comment: Bearing in mind that the repulsive force between two electrons is about $10^{40}$ times as strong as their gravitational attraction, such an object would probably not be stable - i.e. it would spontaneously explode.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called [charge trapping](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/microscopy-and-microanalysis/article/charge-trapping-in-dielectrics/7D2EF415676605C586AAC8C4277D76AE) and it arises as both an intentional and unintentional effect of various processes. It is for example how flash memory works. It's also used for various industrial processes which need to charge up a dielectric for a length of time.

The main problem with making a *permanent* electric dipole using this method is that no material is a perfect insulator. With a lot of charges accumulated in one place, there will be a huge local electric field, and charges will inevitably diffuse into or out of the material. And the more charge you try to fit in a space, the faster this process will happen. If you somehow manage to fit a *huge* amount of charge into some space, it will tear itself apart.

[This paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3727/13/7/031) gives an overview of charge trapping in polyethylene films and gives some figures for how much charge is possible (it's something like one electron per 10,000 atoms) and the stability of such materials.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is called an electret. They can be produced by melting a very highly dielectric material and then letting it cool in the presence of a strong E field. The E field polarizes the material and then the cooling fixes the polarization.

Comment: These are dipoles. I was thinking of an object with an overall negative charge.